# Exception in submit of redux-form not being logged but supressed silently

Tags: exception, reactjs, console.log, redux-form

I have a redux form that I am submitting using the standard handleSubmit. In my `submit()` function I get some errors (due to my own logic), an attribute does not exist. However this error is just suppressed silently and no red console logs are shown saying there is an error and other info. The Redux logged simple shows an action `redux-form/SET_SUBMIT_FAILED` with no other info . How can I get an error log in this scenario?

[image: Console logs with first log line printed but nothing else after that]

```
<MyButton
    onClick={this.props.handleSubmit(submit)}
>
    List Now
</MyButton>
```

### submit function

```
function submit(values) {
    console.log("Submit called")        // this gets logged

    const url = 'store/listing/';

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
    }

    let formData = new FormData();

    const valuesAsJS = updatedValues.toJS()

    Object.keys(valuesAsJS).forEach(key =>formData.append(key, valuesAsJS[key]))

    let i
    for (i=0; i<valuesAsJS.images.length; i++){                 // error here as valuesAsJS.images is undefined
        formData.append('image[]', valuesAsJS.images[i])
    }

    // no more logs happen whatsover and the system freezes, with 
    console.log("Submitting form response for listing creation")


    return api_request({url, options, body: formData})
        .then(response=> {

            if (response.ok && response.status == 201) {


                console.log("Listing creation success")

            } else {
                // not created show error

                console.log("Erorr creating listing")
                throw new SubmissionError({code: "Please re-enter or try again later", _error: true})

            }
        })
}
```